# Best way to share data between steps in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm developing a job that reads a .csv file and stores each record in a database. To do this, I need to use the configuration that I get from the database.
As I don't want to be retreiving the same information for each record. Would JobExecutionContext be the best way to share this information, or there is another alternative?
If I use JobExecutionContext, what would be the best place to store the configuration in a jobParameter? A listener?

Answer (score 2):

The `JobExecutionContext` is a good place to share such a global static configuration information.

Job parameters are more suited for "business" parameters of a batch job (like the input file, input table, partition description, etc). I would not recommend to use them for technical configuration parameters.